# File gitignore does not work: how can I make it ignore files in subfolders?

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore file is not working, I tried all the solutions that I found online, none of them works. Here is what I have: Here `home` is the root directory, and the git repository is in `home/.git`. I added `home/data` to `.gitignore`

```
my_computer home % cat .gitignore
data
```

The file data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat has some text in it

```
my_computer home % ls -l data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 my_computer  staff  3239 Oct 26 11:07 data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat
```

I edit the file data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat

```
my_computer home % ls -l data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 my_computer  staff  3244 Oct 26 11:08 data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat
```

Then I try to switch branch, but the file data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat is not ignored

```
my_computer home % git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    data/storage/analysis/quotient.dat
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file `quotient.dat` is checked in on `master`. `.gitignore` does not affect files already checked in.
You have a few options:

- you want to keep your edits: stash, switch branch, apply stash
- you want to keep the master edits: discard, switch branch